# Merging two table entries into one using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, sql, merge

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

I have a pretty simple task but I just can not find an answer to it. I have one Polygon-Feature with many entries. I just want to merge two selected FIDs into one. So I don't want to dissolve the whole Multi-Part Feature into one Single-Part Feature.

Is there any way to merge them?

And is there a Short-Cut to do it fix (Ctrl+M does not work)?

Comment: Does this [help page on the Merge tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you really much!